# Optimizing repeatedly called math function

Tags: performance, optimization, f#

I am writing some code as part of a nonlinear regression tool and I am trying to figure out an approach for returning the nth partial derivative of a given function in a way that is a good balance of readable and fast. The function (and the analytic representations of the partials) are known at runtime, these can be hardcoded. Here's what I have so far (which works):

```
let getPartials (paramVect: array<float>) idx =
    let a = paramVect.[0]
    let b = paramVect.[1]
    let c = paramVect.[2]
    match idx with
    | 1 -> (fun  x -> (1.0+b+c*x)**(-1.0/b)) // df(x)/da
    | 2 -> (fun  x -> ((a*(1.0+c*b*x)**(-(b+1.0)/b))*((b*c*x+1.0)*Math.Log(b*c*x+1.0)-b*c*x))/(b*b))       // df(x)/db
    | 3 -> (fun  x -> -a*x*(b*c*x+1.0)**(-(b+1.0)/b))   //  df/dc
    | _ -> (fun x  -> 0.0)   //everything else is zero
```

The way I am using this is to first construct a partial function with the parameter vector so that I am minimizing the number of times that needs to be passed in. Then I am repeatedly calling (getPartials(i) x_val) to construct a jacobian. This function gets called an extremely large number of times over the lifecycle the program.

I am getting pretty acceptable performance with this, however, I suspect it can be improved. Profiling shows that the evaluation of the 2nd function calcuation (the long one) is a cpu drain - can this be optimized? I am unsure if the anonymous functions create a performance problem, as readable as it is...

I am *brand new* to F# programming, so please let me know if you spot any egregarious problems with either the style/form or the performance!

Thank you

---

Update: after implementing the changes suggested by **JohnPalmer** and refactoring so that instead of returning an anonymous function which accepts the x-value as an argument, it instead does the whole calculation in-place, I am seeing approximately a 300% speed increase. It was more convenient to be able to return the partial functions, but not worth the cost.

```
let getPartials  (paramVect: array<float>) idx x =
let a = paramVect.[0]
let b = paramVect.[1]
let cbx =  paramVect.[1] * paramVect.[2] * x

match idx with
| 1 -> (1.0+cbx)**(-1.0/b) // df(x)/da
| 2 -> ((a*(1.0+cbx)**(-(b+1.0)/b))*((cbx+1.0)*Math.Log(cbx+1.0)-cbx))/(b**2.0) // df(x)/db
| 3 ->  -a*x*(cbx+1.0)**(-(b+1.0)/b)      //  df/dc
| _ ->  0.0                               //everything else is zero
```

Comment: There are a few common subexpressions you could convert to constants that might help - for example `b*c*x`.  If you knew that certain parameters were always large or small it might be possible to simplify some expressions at the expense of accuraccy.  Also, float32 is faster than float if you can take the accuraccy penalty.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I'm sure I've read somewhere that float32 is often slower than float because calculations are actually done in the FPU with the same precision, but for float32 you have more rounding operations when truncating the values.

Comment: Does the profiler in fact indicate that the speed increase is due to the reduced amount of multiplication?  Check your GC statistics -- that strikes me as a far more likely source of improved performance.

Comment: You're right, it's not really the multiplication which is the problem. Lots of learning today for me...

Comment: @NMR Processors are very fast these days!

Comment: I don't know about the rounding thing but there are definitely advantages in terms of memory bandwidth and cache impact with narrower types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for the anonymous functions to cause a performance problem would be the fact that you create a new heap object each time you call the getPartials function.  If you have only a small number of different `paramVect`s then you might get some performance benefit by caching the anonymous functions.

As for the evaluation of the second expression, you might try this (taking John Palmer's suggestion to eliminate the common subexpressions):

```
fun  x -> let bcx = b * c * x
          let bcx1 = bcx + 1.0
          a * bcx1 ** (-(b+1.0)/b) * (bcx1 * Math.Log bcx1 - bcx)/(b*b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have made some changes to the OP to reflect some new changes I've tried (in line with your & JohnPalmers suggestions). Ditching the anonymous functions ultimately sped the thing up many multiples. ParamVector changes thousands of times, so I cannot cache it.